# Laravel insert into new form, with existing users

Tags: php, laravel, forms, insert

I've created a new form for existing users.
And i'm trying to insert the new values into the database, but the values wont save.

```
 public function editUser(Request $request, $id, $check)
{
    $curID = $id;
    $userData = $request->input();
    $curUser = User::Where('id', $curID)->first();
    $address = Address::where('id', $userData['address_id']);

   ------Not working----------------
    if(empty($curUser->$address)){
        $curUser->insert($address)([
            'address_id'       => $address->id,
            'region_id'        => $userData['region'],
            'country_id'       => $userData['country'],
            'city_id'          => $userData['city'],
            'street_name'      => $userData['street_name'],
            'house_number'     => $userData['house_number'],
            'postcode'         => $userData['postcode']
        ]);
        -------Not working----------------
    } else{

$address->update([
    'region_id'        => $userData['region'],
    'country_id'       => $userData['country'],
    'city_id'          => $userData['city'],
    'street_name'   => $userData['street_name'],
    'house_number'  => $userData['house_number'],
    'postcode'      => $userData['postcode'],
]);
return redirect('client')->with($this->messageBag, "User edited!");
}
```

Comment: You are inserting the address in the user instance `$curUser->insert()`, I guess you want to `$address->insert()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public function editUser(Request $request, $id, $check)
{

   $user = User::where('id',$id)->first();
   $address = Address::where('id',$request->input('address_id'))->first();

    if(empty($address)){
         $address=new Address();
     }
     $address=$this->saveData($address,$request()->all());
     $user->update(['address_id'=>$address->id]);
     return redirect('client')->with($this->messageBag, "User edited!");
}



protected function saveData(Address $address,array $userData){
            $address->region_id= $userData['region'];
            $address->country_id= $userData['country'];
            $address->city_id= $userData['city'];
            $address->street_name= $userData['street_name'];
            $address->house_number= $userData['house_number'];
            $address->postcode= $userData['postcode'];
            $address->save();
            return $address;
}
```

Comment: ah yeh, thnx. it inserts data now. but not connecting with the user.id

Comment: Now, i need to pass the current user's ID with the address_id

Comment: Not fully functional yet

Comment: The address information succesfully get;s inserted into the database. It's not connecting with the current user his ID.

Comment: can you please add your user table and address table structure to question , i can get more clear

Comment: @Michael , are you saving user_id in address table ?  or address_id in user table ?

Comment: address_id in the users table

Comment: @Michael , please try this code , and let me know if it is working proper or not ?

Comment: Call to undefined method App\Services\AccountService::saveData()

Comment: @Michael , add this two methods in your controller

Comment: the saveData() function called inside editUser() function , to save data